# Xamarin sider.dll missing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've upgraded and downgraded my project, now do I get an error message that my `Sider.dll` is missing.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Sider, Version=0.9.3.42023, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   Bestandsnaam: Sider.dll
>      bij Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      bij Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      bij Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)  Scanner.Android

[image]

**Update:**

The error is comming from `ZXing.Net.Mobile Barcode Scanner`. I can only install an older version of this package. Since my `Arc.Barcodes` doesn't support newer versions. I've tried to use diffrent versions without success. Each version has the same `missing sider.dll`error.

If I install a newer version I will get the error message:

> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.1.47' is not compatible with 'Acr.BarCodes 3.1.0 constraint: ZXing.Net.Mobile (>= 1.4.7.1 && < 2.0.0)'.

I hope that someone can help me finding an answer for this problem.

Comment: When I go to the GitHub page of [Arc.Barcodes](https://github.com/aritchie/barcodes) it says:
`#THIS LIBRARY IS NOW DEPRECATED. THIS WAS NOTHING MORE THAN A PCL BRIDGE FOR ZXING.NET.MOBILE. ZXING IS NOW PCL OUT OF THE BOX!` So I recommend using the latest version of ZXing.Net.Mobile and to not use Arc.Barcodes as it is a deprecated library. This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to rebuild the project and install the oldest version? If you fail, you can try.
For creating a Barcode Scanner, I will use the NuGet package Arc.BarCodes, a cross-platform creator built on top of ZXing.Net.Mobile to allow for easy cross-platform access from Shared/PCL core libraries.
Now we can set some permissions for Android and Windows to get access to the camera. This is for taking the clear picture of the barcode that we want to scan.

For Android open the AndroidManifest.xml and select CAMERA from the Required Permissions
Now open WMAppManifest.xml for setting permissions to Windows Phone then selectID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA from Capabilities.
Now we want to initialize the corresponding NuGet package in each platform-specific startup classes. For example, AppDelegate.cs for iOS, MainActivity.cs for Android and MainPage.xaml.cs for Windows Phone by calling global::Acr.BarCodes.BarCodes.Init(); before calling LoadApplication();

Now create a button on the page for the Barcode Scanner.